# Flutter AnimatedSize works in one direction only

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have got following code from https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-working-with-animatedsize-35253ff8f16a

it is using AnimatedSize, but animation works only while container is expanding and not while is it shirking. is this the default behavior? I want to animated while both expanding and shriking.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  double _height = 80.0;
  double _width = 80.0;
  var _color = Colors.blue;
  bool _resized = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedSize(
              curve: Curves.easeIn,
              vsync: this,
              duration: new Duration(seconds: 1),
              child: new GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_resized) {
                      _resized = false;
                      _color = Colors.blue;
                      _height = 80.0;
                      _width = 80.0;
                    } else {
                      _resized = true;
                      _color = Colors.blue;
                      _height = 320.0;
                      _width = 320.0;
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: new Container(
                  width: _width,
                  height: _height,
                  color: _color,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is a bug

Comment: @ Ali80 Yeah it's a bug, and a five year old one at that. It's been closed because they didn't do anything about it and now no-one can respond there https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21384

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AnimatedContainer` is what you are looking for no need for `AnimatedSize`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  double _height = 80.0;
  double _width = 80.0;
  var _color = Colors.blue;
  bool _resized = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (_resized) {
                    _resized = false;
                    _color = Colors.blue;
                    _height = 80.0;
                    _width = 80.0;
                  } else {
                    _resized = true;
                    _color = Colors.blue;
                    _height = 320.0;
                    _width = 320.0;
                  }
                });
              },
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                width: _width,
                height: _height,
                color: _color,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or if you need `AnimatedSize` you can add a new container with the color as the `AnimatedSize` parent.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double _height = 320.0;
  double _width = 320.0;
  var _color = Colors.blue;
  bool _resized = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              if (_resized) {
                _resized = false;
                _color = Colors.blue;
                _height = 80.0;
                _width = 80.0;
              } else {
                _resized = true;
                _color = Colors.blue;
                _height = 320.0;
                _width = 320.0;
              }
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            color: _color,
            child: AnimatedSize(
              curve: Curves.easeIn,
              vsync: this,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              child: Container(
                width: _width,
                height: _height,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: AnimatedContainer is mostly useless because it only animates on fixed heights. AnimatedSize is great because it adjusts it's size automatically based on how many items are contained there. Pity it has this buy that was reported 5 years ago and nobody looked at.

Answer (score 25):

AnimatedContainer isn't really an option when using text, lists or other variably sized widgets because it doesn't allow a width or height of null. Also it won't let you specify an alignment.

Instead I fixed this using a ClipRect with an animation controller. In the animation below you can see the word 'laboris' on the left of the center line in the closing bounce. This shows the text is getting centered during the closing of the container, just keep your eyes on 'laboris'. You can change the alignment for different effects.

[image: animation example]

I created an AnimatedClipRect widget class that you can easily implement yourself. You can specify alignment, curves, durations and if you want horizontal and/or vertical animation. As it is now it assumes you just want to fully close or open it:

```
class AnimatedClipRect extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedClipRectState createState() => _AnimatedClipRectState();

  final Widget child;
  final bool open;
  final bool horizontalAnimation;
  final bool verticalAnimation;
  final Alignment alignment;
  final Duration duration;
  final Duration? reverseDuration;
  final Curve curve;
  final Curve? reverseCurve;

  ///The behavior of the controller when [AccessibilityFeatures.disableAnimations] is true.
  final AnimationBehavior animationBehavior;

  const AnimatedClipRect({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.open,
    this.horizontalAnimation = true,
    this.verticalAnimation = true,
    this.alignment = Alignment.center,
    this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    this.reverseDuration,
    this.curve = Curves.linear,
    this.reverseCurve,
    this.animationBehavior = AnimationBehavior.normal,
  }) : super(key: key);
}

class _AnimatedClipRectState extends State<AnimatedClipRect> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation _animation;

  @override
  void dispose() {
     _animationController.dispose();
     super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
        duration: widget.duration,
        reverseDuration: widget.reverseDuration ?? widget.duration,
        vsync: this,
        value: widget.open ? 1.0 : 0.0,
        animationBehavior: widget.animationBehavior);
    _animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: widget.curve,
      reverseCurve: widget.reverseCurve ?? widget.curve,
    ));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    widget.open ? _animationController.forward() : _animationController.reverse();

    return ClipRect(
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _animationController,
        builder: (_, child) {
          return Align(
            alignment: widget.alignment,
            heightFactor: widget.verticalAnimation ? _animation.value : 1.0,
            widthFactor: widget.horizontalAnimation ? _animation.value : 1.0,
            child: child,
          );
        },
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Basic usage example, put whatever you want to animate in its child:

```
// declare bool _open somewhere

Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    AnimatedClipRect(
      open: _open,
      horizontalAnimation: false,
      verticalAnimation: true,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      curve: Curves.bounceOut,
      reverseCurve: Curves.bounceIn,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: const Text(
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'),
      ),
    ),
    ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text("open/close"),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() => _open ^= true);
        }),
  ],
)
```

As you can see all you have to do is change _open and do setState((){}) to trigger the animation.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. I really like that the animation controller is hidden inside the widget - hence one can control the sliding animation by just changing `open:boolean` value. Kudos!

Comment: dont forget to dispose your controllers tho

Comment: Thanks, these disposes are too easy to forget. I also updated the code to work with null safety and added some more consts here and there.

Comment: This is a kind of widget flutter should provide as the use cases are very high for such thing.
Great widget though. This helps to keep the layout file clean

Comment: This is pretty amazing.  Just tried it and it works like a charm.  Right now I put it in a listview and it pushes content down (appropriately as intended)-- but is it possible to have it push upwards? so that any text above it actually is pushed upwards rather then pushing content below it down

Comment: that's amazing.

Comment: @Mark try adding this before return Align(...):           if (widget.open) {
            WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
              Scrollable.ensureVisible(
                context,
                alignmentPolicy: ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.keepVisibleAtEnd,
              );
            });
          }

Comment: I highly recommend moving `widget.open ? _animationController.forward() : _animationController.reverse();` to didUpdateWidget()

Comment: That looks quite good but it's not actually animating the size, it's just moving up off the screen. To animate the size, the lorem ipsum line should stay still and the bottom should stretch down to hide and reveal the text.

Comment: The example uses Alignment.center, just changing it to top should make it behave as you describe.

Comment: @Janneman I tried it and unfortunately it doesn't work anything like AnimatedSize anyway. AnimatedSize is the only widget that adjusts it's size to the size and number of widgets it contains. So I can have a container with a column of two lines of text, increase it to size lines and it will animate its size accordingly and then back again. If it weren't for the bug that was reported 5 years ago I'd just use that.

Comment: @Hasen It's using a ClipRect so maybe that doesn't work out for you. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve and I haven't used Flutter for a while either. Good luck!

Comment: @Janneman Anything using an animation controller like that which is just going from 0 to 1 would not achieve this since it can only go from full size to some arbitrary size and back to full size. It couldn't go from exactly the right size as needed to show two lines of text, up to the size of ten lines of text and back again since you don't know what the smaller size is. AnimatedSize can do that.

Answer (score 2):

Widget `SizeTransition` worked for me. It works when the child height or width is `null` too.

Here is my sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    vsync: this,
  );
  late final Animation<double> _animation = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          SizeTransition(
            sizeFactor: _animation,
            axis: Axis.vertical,
            axisAlignment: 1,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: const [Text("Hello"), Text("World")],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('toggle'),
            onPressed: () => _controller.isDismissed
                ? _controller.forward()
                : _controller.reverse(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Animated Size was giving me the same problem as for you, but then I looked into AnimatedCrossFade's source code, and it used Animated Size and it animated size both while shrinking and expanding. Use LayoutBuilder as child of AnimatedSize and put the actual child inside LayoutBuilder. I'm not sure why it works, but that was how it was for AnimatedCrossFade.

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed that `AnimatedSize` fails in "one direction" when transitioning to a layout that contains `RichText`.  I was able to work around this simply by wrapping the text in a sized box with a fixed height (providing a height for the layout).  If you are experiencing `AnimatedSize` seemingly not working in random situations try adding fixed size constraints to your layout and see if it helps.