# Animating expanding / contracting on widgets of unknown size

Tags: flutter, animation

We want of to display a list of images and text that we fetch from a database. When you tap on one of the images / texts, they should expand with an animation. With the current code, the expanding animation works as intended, but the opposite does not work. The image shrinks without an animation, and then the `AnimatedSize` animates. See: [Flutter AnimatedSize works in one direction only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59132930/flutter-animatedsize-works-in-one-direction-only)

Since we don't have a solid color the solution to that question does not really work for us.

It does work with the images with the following code, but it's not ideal and text does not work at all that way.

```dart
Container(
  foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
        snapshot.data.documents[index]['image'],
      ),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    ),
  ),
  child: AnimatedSize(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    vsync: this,
    child: Opacity(
      opacity: 0,
      child: Container(
        height: _expandedIndex == index ? null : 250,
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: snapshot.data.documents[index]['image'] ?? '',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: double.infinity,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

I have found a lot of other people with the same problem, but I have never found a solution that works, so any help is very welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use a `sizeTransition` Widget.
and set up your `animationController` and `Tween<double>`

and it should work fine, I've used it and it worked in both directions forward and reverse.

Comment: How do I animate between two sizes with SizeTransition? Even if I use Tween<double>(begin: 200, end: double.infinity).animate(controller) The animation always starts at 0

Comment: use ```controller.forward()``` and ```controller.reverse()``` to toggle between the two, or use this toggle function ```Future<void> toggle() => _controller.isDismissed ? _controller.forward() : _controller.reverse();```. and apply it on the container onTap().

Answer (score 0):

Tried `sizeTransition` widget, and it worked for me. `AnimationController` and `Tween` are not necessary. Here is my worked code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    vsync: this,
  );
  late final Animation<double> _animation = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('toggle'),
            onPressed: () => _controller.isDismissed
                ? _controller.forward()
                : _controller.reverse(),
          ),
          SizeTransition(
            sizeFactor: _animation,
            axis: Axis.vertical,
            axisAlignment: -1,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: const [Text("Hello"), Text("World")],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```